# Why did China hate dogs? Why were dogs abject creatures in China?

Tags: china, animals

I quote  [page 240](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Return_to_the_Middle_Kingdom/t8wdOqCde-YC?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover&pg=PA240&dq=%22dogs%20are%20abject%20creatures%22) in  Yuan-tsung Chen's 2008 *Return to the Middle Kingdom | One Family, Three Revolutionaries, and the Birth of Modern China*. This quote flummoxes me! I have a pet dog! I live in a society where dog is man's best friend! I am not Chinese, so please explain in simple English.

> "If you think you can silence the people, you had better think again,"
> Borodin retorted irascibly. "Let me tell you a story. In ancient times, there
> was a king in the West who became nettled by the different opinions from
> his ministers. One day he said to them: 'You all talk too much. I don't like it.'
> They replied: 'Dogs cannot talk back. If Your Majesty does not like to hear
> us talk, then go find dogs.
>         Borodin could not have found a worse insult to throw in Chiang Kaishek's
> face. In this instance, Borodin's lack of knowledge of Chinese culture was
> thoroughly exposed. In the West, a dog is man's best friend; **but in China,
> dogs are abject creatures.** In Chinese, no idiomatic expression was more
> demeaning than the term ["running dogs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Running_dog)." It was said that after this exchange
> of violent words, Chiang made up his mind to expel Borodin from China.
> Chiang stayed in Hankou a short while, in order to drive wedges between
> Borodin and the leading Kuomintang members. His overture to Eugene was
> most obvious. Chiang, a total stranger to Western culture, went to a dance
> concert organized and showcased by Silan. Though bored, he sat through the
> entire performance and flattered her on her choreography.

Comment: Many cultures have negative views of dogs, the Hebrew Bible and English idioms being two familiar ones. Probably related to their slavish behaviour and willingness to scavenge, but maybe there's more to it.

Comment: I wonder if social relationship with dogs is correlated with urbanization, or with hunting?  Or is it East/West?  Probably better for sociology than history, but might be a place to start research.

Comment: It is not just China. Most if not all Eastern cultures held (And predominantly still hold) dog as an abject creature., seen as dirty and impure who could also make you dirty by merely touching. They were still kept for practical reasons such as sheep herding, watch dogs, hunting hounds etc. So you can say that in the East, the dog is tolerated, not cherished.

Comment: My family in China has a pet dog, and they love it. And many families around like dogs as well. This source is a little weird.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not true that dogs have traditionally been hated in China. China is a big place, and its history is very long. The Chinese have had a variety of attitudes about dogs, and they've used dogs for a variety of purposes. There are [ancient artifacts](https://www.sixthtone.com/news/1001742/7%2C000-years-of-the-dog-a-history-of-chinas-canine-companions) depicting guard dogs in alert poses, as well as dogs catching rats. Dogs have sometimes been eaten in Chinese culture. There is a year of the dog, and dogs are considered lucky. Dogs have [religious symbolism](https://www.worldhistory.org/article/1327/dogs-in-ancient-china/), representing the protective power of the Buddha.

Other cultures are like this as well. For instance, in the Iliad, dogs are depicted both positively and negatively. The Homeric heroes insult each other by calling each other dogs, but at the same time we have dog metaphors to show people as heroic warriors: "But Hector went in the van, looking grim through ferocity; as when some dog,
relying on his swift feet, seizes from the rear a wild boar or lion on the
haunch and buttocks, and marks him as he turns: so Hector hung on
the rear of the long-haired Greeks, always slaying the hindmost: and
they fled." (Iliad 8.337, translated by Buckley)

In ancient Jewish culture, dogs were regarded somewhat negatively, but at the same time they were intentionally kept and fed. We can see the mix of both attitudes in [Mark 7:27-29](https://ebible.org/web/MRK07.htm), where Jesus compares a Canaanite woman with a dog, which is a racial slur, but at the same time she cleverly turns the tables on him and ends up being granted a miracle.

In modern western culture, we also have a variety of attitudes about dogs. You can call someone a "bitch" or a "dirty dog," but at the same time many people love their dogs a lot.

Comment: This would benefit from focusing on the question that was asked rather than touching on a range of other cultures to pad it out.